# Is there a way to subdivide a cube while a shape of a sphere is maintained?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Is there a way to subdivide a cube while a shape of a sphere is maintained? When making changes on a cube (with subdivision surface, bevel etc.), instead of pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, the shape of a sphere to be maintained. Is something like that possible to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this **non destructively** by adding a subdivision surface modifier set to *simple*, and a cast modifier with the *Cast type* set the sphere and the factor set to *1*.

Another method is <kbd>W</kbd>>*Subdivide smooth* will come close to achieving the effect you want, as far as I know, it doesn't divide correctly, and will create a mesh that isn't quite spherical.

Screen shot of modifier settings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I knew that there was some kind of a modifier for that, but I forgot that it is the Cast modifier.

Comment: @Vladimir if my post helped you, please mark it as accepted.